# Meteor app not starting up. Was working on 0.7.0.1. Doesn't on 0.7.1 or 0.7.2

Tags: meteor

The following is what I get when I start up my app:

> - meteor [[[[[ ~/......./app ]]]]]
>
> => Started proxy.
>   => Started MongoDB.
>   => Starting your app...

It used to work on Meteor 0.7.1, but when I upgraded to 0.7.2 it never finishes loading up. Now I can't even run it on 0.7.1, only 0.7.0.1.

This happens to all my meteor apps on my computer. Any ideas of what the problem is or how I debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a badly commented CSS file. I opened a comment tag in a CSS file and didn't close it which is what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've posted this a couple of times. I've seen the problem with some of my projects. While I can't guarantee it will work, I hope it gives you a bit of an idea of where to look to clear your older data.

Look for all `.build` folders in your project and delete them.

```
cd your-project-name
rm -rf .build
cd .meteor
rm -rf .build
```

(Also repeat the same for your package folders)

Comment: This didn't work, but thanks. Any other ideas? I've only posted it once here and once on meteor-talk btw.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your install of Meteor is corrupt. Do a clean install:

Uninstall Meteor:

```
sudo rm `where meteor`
rm -rf ~/.meteor
```

Uninstall Meteorite:

```
sudo mrt uninstall
sudo mrt uninstall --system
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

Install Meteor:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

Install Meteorite:

```
http://oortcloud.github.io/meteorite/
```